# How to performance tuning the limit sentence?

Tags: mysql

I run the following MYSQL sentence, however it spends over 10 seconds, although it just return 10 rows. BTW, if I remove the LIMIT 0, 10 , it would return 1,000,000 rows.I  have created Index1 for column SceneCode and Index2 for column ProviderId.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT * FROM gf_sceneprovider WHERE SceneCode='DL00000003'    ) AS sprovider
    LEFT JOIN  (SELECT * FROM gf_sceneprovidertemplate WHERE SceneCode='DL00000003'      ) AS stemplate
ON sprovider.ProviderId = stemplate.ProviderId
    INNER JOIN gf_provider AS provider 
ON provider.ProviderId = sprovider.ProviderId 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

[image]

Comment: So you want to get 10 records without any rules? If yes, maybe you can try to limit the `gf_sceneprovider` before the left join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do away with the subqueries in favor of direct joins:

```
SELECT *
FROM gf_sceneprovider sprovider
LEFT JOIN gf_sceneprovidertemplate stemplate
    ON sprovider.ProviderId = stemplate.ProviderId
INNER JOIN gf_provider AS provider 
    ON provider.ProviderId = sprovider.ProviderId 
WHERE sprovider.SceneCode = 'DL00000003' AND
      stemplate.SceneCode = 'DL00000003'
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Then, add indices on the join columns if possible.  Your original subqueries might prevent the indices on the `gf_sceneprovider` and `gf_sceneprovidertemplate` tables from being used effectively/at all.  The reason for this is that your subqueries essentially create an on-the-fly table which, unlike the tables from which they select, have no indices.  I think some RDMBS can cope with this in certain scenarios but it looks like that is not the case here.

Comment: fantastic! now your sentence is very fast. may I know why  my original subqueries might prevent the indices on the gf_sceneprovider and gf_sceneprovidertemplate tables from being used effectively/at all?

Comment: @Jason I gave you the reason, read the bottom of my answer.  There are no indices on a temp/intermediate table in your case.

Comment: thank you so much Tim, I  got a very useful knowledge from you.

Comment: Can you help to check the query plan, it seems both your and my sentences use the index, however my query use the full table scan, can you explain why this happens? I update the query plan to the question just now.

Comment: I marked it, however it is better if you can help to check the query plan.

Comment: The sprovider  (materialized)  and (stemplate) materialized  meaning the temp table for the sprovider and   stemplate?

Comment: The query plan looks OK to me. You have a single full table scan on `sprovider` (you have to), but everything else uses indices.

Comment: Yes , both your and mine use the index except the single full table scan  on sprovider ,  if I run the SELECT * FROM gf_sceneprovider WHERE SceneCode='DL00000003' alone, it return 50,0000 rows in 1 seconds, however your sentence retun near 0 second, my sentence return over 10 seconds, why have a such big difference?

Comment: why It have to full table scan on sprovider ?from the  query plan, it use the index SceneCode_SearchFirstKeyWord first, then full table scan, why also need the full table scan after use the index SceneCode_SearchFirstKeyWord?

Comment: When you join two tables, you _always_ do a full scan on one of the tables.  The value of the index is that it speeds up matching each record in the first table to the second table.

Comment: @However why there is no  full scan  in the second  query plan, which geneated from the  sentence from you ?